# Getting props to change an HTML value in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make a math quiz with React.  Basically when the user clicks the button, it will tally how many radio buttons had a value of "correct" and were "checked."  Because I wanted to challenge myself, I'm try to put the questions into customizable components.  A question component, which I've started to build, will look like this:

```
    export default function Question(props) {
  var answersArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  answersArray[parseInt(props.choice)].value = "correct";

  return (
    <>
      <p>What is {props.equation}</p>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="g" /> 4
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="g" /> 3
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="g" /> 5
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="g" /> 2
      <br />
      <br />
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is, even if I'm passing down the prop in the Quiz component (the component which will contain the Question components), and even if I use "useEffect", I get an error that `answersArray[parseInt(...)]` is undefined.

How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 2):

Direct DOM manipulation is almost always the wrong approach in React.

It *looks like* the only indication which connects `props.choice` to the "correct" answer is just that answer's position in the UI.  In that case each one could check the prop and render its `value` accordingly.  For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value={props.choice === 0 ? "correct" : "g"} /> 4
```

The next one could check `=== 1`, then `=== 2`, and so on.

Basically the logic for what should be rendered would be part of the rendering, rather than trying to manually update the DOM after the rendering.